# Why is property null when its value is assigned using __get()?

Tags: php

I've made a class:

```
class MyClass {
    function __get($name) {
        $this->{$name} = $_SESSION[$name];
    }

    public function isNull(){
        return $this->MyVar === null;
    }
}
```

`var_dump($obj->isNull()) //$obj is instance of MyClass` always outputs `bool(true)` doesn't matter `$_SESSION['MyVar']` is set or not. But if I add `$this->MyVar;` before `return $this->MyVar === null;` works as expected.

Well it seems that `__get()` is executed (because `$MyVar` is not set so it's inaccessible) but property stays NULL until second usage.

Does it happen because it's not set at all? How can I avoid using extra line (`$this->MyVar;`)?

Comment: Why are you setting a property in a getter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__get()` must return the value. Change it to:

```
function __get($name) {
    return $_SESSION[$name];
}
```